# Liquibase: UPDATE script (when some changes has already implemented in the database)

Tags: database, migration, liquibase

Ok, so the problem is probably in my approach to liquibase, I have implemented some changes in the database side, and I want to create changesets, so I simply add a new sql file to my changesets. When I try to run luquibase update command I get error which tells me that some columns exist in the database.

For me is normal that before I create the changesets script I try to add columns in the database (i.e. using PhpMyAdmin). Then I want to share with this changes with other developers, so I generate sql (from my changes), adding this in the sql file and launching this file in changeset.
Can somebody tell me what I make wrong?

The problem concerns situation when I added some new columns to my mysql table, thenI created sql file whit alter_table script and thenI run liquibase update command.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make manual updates in your database. All schema changes have to be done with liquibase or else - as in your case - your changesets will conflict with the existing schema.

Comment: I know that the problem became from my duplication of sql alter. So the best solution is to have two databases? One for testing a new sql and second one for deployment?

Comment: No. If you want to make a change you create a new changeset and apply it locally. Never make changes to your database manually.

Comment: Locally = testing in my case. I hoped that Liquibase is able to recognize my changes in the database and can integrate them with changesets. Unfortunately not. Of course I can use only changesets, but sometimes is better for me (especially with related tables) to create sql in PhpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

While having all changes to your database be done with Liquibase before hand is ideal, there are certainly situations where that is not possible. One is the use case you've described. Another would be if a hotfix is applied to production and needs to be merged back to development.

If you are certain that your changeset has been applied to the environment, then consider running [changelogSync](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html). It will assert that all changesets have been applied and will update the Liquibase meta table with the appropriate information.

Although not ideal, we think that that changelogSync is required for real world applications where sometimes life does not progress as we would like. That's why we made certain to expose it clearly in Datical DB. We think it strikes a balance between reality and idealism.